# Override the transition delay in React Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I created `motion.div` component, which contains `initial`, `animate` and `whileTap` properties:

```
<motion.button
  initial={'initial'}
  animate={'in'}
  whileTap={'onTap'}
  variants={introButtonVariants}
>...</>
```

`in` variation contains `transition` with the `delay: 0.5`:

```
in: {
  x: 0,
  scale: 1,
  transition: { duration: 0.5, delay: 0.5 }
}
```

But this `delay: 0.5` is affecting `onTap` variation, even if I explicitly specify new `delay` there. So on tap, it instantly goes in the "tapped" mode but then it stops for `0.5s.` before backward animation.

```
onTap: {
  scale: 0.8,
  transition: { scale: { delay: 0 } }
}
```

How can the `delay` value, which goes to `animate` property, be overridden by the new one, which is defined in the new variation?

Comment: Just tried to replicate your scenario but it looks like `in` and `onTap` animations use their own delays. Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-chatelet-kp80u?file=/src/App.js). Check yourself

Comment: Sorry, I misconstructed the question. Now I can see that animation starts at the right time but it stucks in the "activated" mode for a 1.5s. And I desired to have the movement which doesn't stop and deactivates with the same speed as activates. Thanks for your effort in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was faced with the same problem and found an answer in official discord.
Looks like at this moment it's only possible with spread operator to reset delay in animate state.

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/motion-transition-70yhg?file=/src/App.js

Copypaste:

```
const size = 200;
const radius = 40;
const color = "#0CF";
const curve = {
    type: "spring",
    stiffness: 400,
    damping: 30
};

export default function App() {
    const variants = {
        active: { scale: 1.25, transition: { ...curve, delay: 2 } },
        hovering: {
            scale: 1.5,
            rotate: 180,
            transition: { ...curve, delay: 0 }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <motion.div
                style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    backgroundColor: color,
                    borderRadius: radius
                }}
                variants={variants}
                animate={"active"}
                whileHover={"hovering"}
                transition={{ ...curve }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```