# framer-motion custom hover variant is affected by a delay from another variant

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I have a set of variants defined as such:

```js
const letterVariants: Variants = {
  visible: (custom: number) => ({
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      delay: custom * 0.1,
    },
  }),
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 100,
  },
  hover: {
    y: -30,
    transition: {
      delay: 0,
    },
  },
};
```

which are used for the hero title:

```js
<h1 className="font-peralta">
  {letters.map((letter, i) => (
    <motion.div
      className="inline-block"
      variants={letterVariants}
      custom={i}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
      whileHover="hover"
      key={nanoid()}
    >
      {letter}
    </motion.div>
  ))}
</h1>
```

On initial render, each letter of the hero title fades in from the bottom. I am trying to make it also that when I hover (before or after animation end), the letters slide up a bit. The problem I am facing is that the custom transition `delay` that allows for the letters to pop up one-by-one is also applied to the `hover` variant. So when I hover over the first letter, it moves up and down immediately, if I hover over the last letter, it goes up but takes `x * 0.1` seconds to return to its normal position.

It's almost exactly the same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697286/override-the-transition-delay-in-react-framer-motion) post except that solution has not worked for me.